# What happens when toner is over filled?

Tags: laser-printer, toner

I am refilling a laser printer with cheaper toner bought in a bottle. It was suggested to not overfill. Are there any dangers to overfilling?

Can it damage the carthridge or printer? Produce blackened pages? Increase amount of powder used per page?

I am refilling my laser printer Samsung CLP 365. Toner supplier attached some not very impressive instructions paper that looks like just copied off google frankly. (Not in english)

It says toner cartridge should be refilled with a pre-measured amount to only half the cartridge capacity. Is this really necessary? I cannot find any instructions on the internet that also say that. There are many videos on YouTube showing how refilling is done, neither mentions it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Can a Laser Printer Cartridge Be Overfilled?](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/can-laser-printer-cartridge-overfilled-59155.html):

> ...the key is to not overfill the cartridge, as this may result in toner
>   escaping from the cartridge into your printer and causing damage.
>
> **Leakage**
>
> An overfilled cartridge leaks toner out of its refill opening onto the
>   printer's drum, transfer roller, or belt and its fuser, causing
>   printouts to be stained with toner. The loose toner can also travel
>   via any rollers inside of the printer and contaminate any paper
>   present in the printer's paper trays.
>
> **Toner Cartridges**
>
> Toner leaking from overfilled cartridges can also contaminate other
>   toner cartridges, resulting in images and words outputting with the
>   wrong colors. You must then remove and replace/refill the contaminated
>   cartridges to correct the issue.
>
> **Cartridge Seals**
>
> Overfilling a toner cartridge can also damage the cartridge's internal
>   seals and cause them to leak over time, even after the excess toner
>   has leaked out. The seals inside of a cartridge are not
>   user-replaceable. If you notice the cartridge leaking toner from an
>   area other than the component that comes in contact with the drum or
>   the refill opening, one or more seals are leaking.

Toner is constantly turned over and "tilled" with internal mechanisms that even out the toner. It must be a "loose" fill it can't be "packed" tight when the chamber is closed.