# Top smudges after possible toner overfilling

Tags: printing, laser-printer, toner

I was refilling the black toner and filled it to 95% but after a day I realized [that I should not](https://superuser.com/questions/994497/what-happens-when-toner-is-over-filled), so I poured toner back into the bottle (emptied cartridge) and filled it to 50% again. No printing was done in between.

Pages printed since then look very good, thick text. However some pages have some smudge at the top. Some pages have it, some not. After printing 60 pages, I see it more often on those at the end. Pages printed first are  okay.

What can be causing it? And how to get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: It was my 1st impression when I read your question and it is the 1st answer of the link you posted. __Leakage__ _An overfilled cartridge leaks toner out of its refill opening onto the printer's drum..._ If it is so try to clean it. BTW remember that in the toner there are components that can seriously [harm your health](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_black). Use mask, gloves and change the air of the room after.

Comment: @Hastur Strange, today printed another 14 pages. Odd pages were clean, I put them back into tray reversed and printed odd. Seems this only happens to second side. Could it be that the toner does not fuse with paper and the other side of paper leaves traces?

Comment: It can be. BTW update the question with precise details. Is this happening each time you print a particular kind of pages (only text, few toner use - picture ones, a lot of toner used)? It happens only when you put back _used_  pages? It happens only when the printer is _cold_ or _hot_ (used few or a lot)? ... All can help. Mine is the experience of a common user  not more... wait for someone more expert too...

Comment: you might want to clean a lot of things in there. transfer belts and other stuff can have brushes to clear off the loose dribblings and out of margin stuff, there can be tray to collect the toner that falls to the wayside. Rollers that might still have paper dust and toner on them. USually after cleaning everything and cleaning the cleaners , emptying any trays that may exist , that just leaves drums, which even touching them changes it.  I have cleaned drums before but it was crasy methods.